# Devise edit_registration now working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to edit the current user's information using the `edit_user_registration_path`.

This is the code of the edit_registration.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contact_no %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contact_no, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <br />
      <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

After I click the update button, i am redirected another page, and i get a flash message that says 'Your account has been updated successfully.'

But the information is not updated at all, and same old information is being displayed.

Additional Information: 
Also i have some validations in the `user.rb` model file, as:

```
  validates :email, :password, presence: true, on: :create
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true, if: :password_present?
  enum kind: {Admin: 0, Publisher: 1, Editor: 2}

  def password_present?
    password.present?
  end
```

This file is used for the other edit page that i have for user in the path `edit_organization_user_path`.

```
= form_for [current_organization,@user] do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this organization from being saved:"
      ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message
  .field
    = f.label :first_name
    = f.text_field :first_name
  .field
    = f.label :last_name
    = f.text_field :last_name
  .field
    = f.label :contact_no
    = f.text_field :contact_no
  .field
    = f.label :address
    = f.text_field :address
  .field
    = f.label :email
    = f.text_field :email
  .field
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'disabled'
  .field
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  .actions = f.submit
  = link_to "Back", organizations_path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious issue is that you haven't permitted additional parameters, which are just being ignored.

Make sure to read the [Devise Documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), in full.

Most likely fix...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name,
                                                       :last_name,
                                                       :contact_no,
                                                       :address])
  end
end
```

In addition to this...your User validations for `email` and `password` are redundant (Devise handles this validation for you).